# Converter hexadecimal para inteiro

Tags: c#, .net, string, inteiros, hexadecimal

Tenho esse valor em hexadecimal "E365A931A000000".

Preciso converte-lo para inteiro estou utilizando o seguinte código.

```
string hex = "E365A931A000000";
CodLibercao = Convert.ToInt32(hex);
```

Esse código está me mando a seguinte exceção:

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

O que estou fazendo errado na conversão?

Comment: 64 bits é necessário Padawan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltou você usar a base de conversão. Também há um problema porque este número não cabe em um `int`, é preciso usar um `long` ([`Convert.ToInt64()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint64?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToInt64_System_String_System_Int32_)) para realizar a conversão.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var hex = "E365A931A000000";
        WriteLine(ToInt64(hex, 16));
        hex = "E365A931";
        WriteLine(ToInt32(hex, 16));
        hex = "E365A931A000000000";
        WriteLine(BigInteger.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ePY4X6). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UamL1F). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/Hexadecimal.cs).

Mostrei um exemplo com um número menor para caber em um `int`. E uma conversão que acomoda números de qualquer tamanho. Deve-se avaliar se vale à pena usar o [`BigInteger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Numerics_BigInteger_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_) mesmo.

Comment: o Visual retorno o seguinte erro  
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  
Preciso armazenar a conversão em uma variável tipo inteiro.

Comment: Você tem que usar um `long` para isto, o número em hexadecimal é grande demais para caber em um `int`. Ou você trabalha com número menores ou muda o tipo de `CodLibercao`. Editei mostrando um número menor.

Comment: Preciso mesmo trabalhar com esse hexa de 18 caracteres, e continua dando erro tando, ulong, long, int, unit,  "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Você pode colocar seu código completo. Você viu na minha resposta que funciona. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: em console ou no MessageBox, faz em windowsform e armazena em uma variável. Para depois aparecer textbox. Em console eu testei, em messagebox também. Mas eu preciso converter em inteiro realizar o calculo desse hexa com data de hoje, e mostrar em uma textbox. Estou usando C#

Comment: Certo havia me esquecido que var também pode ser usado no C#. valeu. Desculpe pelo ato falho.  
var hex = "E365A931A000000";
long CodLibercao = Convert.ToInt64(hex,16);

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade a conversão de hexadecimal pra inteiro exige o uso de [`Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Int32.Parse(v=vs.110).aspx), [mais especificamente este formato](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c09yxbyt(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var codLiberacao = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

[Só que eu fiz um teste e este hexadecimal é muito grande pra um inteiro de 32 bits](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BQTvlC), então use `long` ou `Int64` para a conversão:

```
var codLiberacao = Int64.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: Já havia usado esse método, e dá essa exceção:  
"Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Faça um F5. Atualizei a resposta.